# Marrying Core Animation with OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, core-animation

*Edit:* I suppose instead of the long explanation below I might also ask: Sending `-setNeedsDisplay` to an instance of `CAEAGLLayer` does not cause the layer to redraw (i.e., `-drawInContext:` is not called). Instead, I get this console message:

> ```
> <GLLayer: 0x4d500b0>: calling -display has no effect.
> ```

Is there a way around this issue? Can I invoke `-drawInContext:` when `-setNeedsDisplay` is called? Long explanation below:

---

I have an OpenGL scene that I would like to animate using Core Animation animations.

Following the standard approach to animate custom properties in a CALayer, I created a subclass of `CAEAGLLayer` and defined a property `sceneCenterPoint` in it whose value should be animated. My layer also holds a reference to the OpenGL renderer:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ES2Renderer.h"

@interface GLLayer : CAEAGLLayer
{
    ES2Renderer *renderer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ES2Renderer *renderer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint sceneCenterPoint;
```

I then declare the property `@dynamic` to let CA create the accessors, override `+needsDisplayForKey:` and implement `-drawInContext:` to pass the current value of the `sceneCenterPoint` property to the renderer and ask it to render the scene:

```
#import "GLLayer.h"

@implementation GLLayer

@synthesize renderer;
@dynamic sceneCenterPoint;

+ (BOOL) needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"sceneCenterPoint"]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
    }
}

- (void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    self.renderer.centerPoint = self.sceneCenterPoint;
    [self.renderer render];
}
...
```

(If you have access to the WWDC 2009 session videos, you can review this technique in session 303 ("Animated Drawing")).

Now, when I create an explicit animation for the layer on the keyPath `@"sceneCenterPoint"`, Core Animation should calculate the interpolated values for the custom properties and call `-drawInContext:` for each step of the animation:

```
- (IBAction)animateButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sceneCenterPoint"];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
    [self.glView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

At least that is what would happen for a normal `CALayer` subclass. When I subclass `CAEAGLLayer`, I get this output on the console for each step of the animation:

> ```
> 2010-12-21 13:59:22.180 CoreAnimationOpenGL[7496:207] <GLLayer: 0x4e0be20>: calling -display has no effect.
> 2010-12-21 13:59:22.198 CoreAnimationOpenGL[7496:207] <GLLayer: 0x4e0be20>: calling -display has no effect.
> 2010-12-21 13:59:22.216 CoreAnimationOpenGL[7496:207] <GLLayer: 0x4e0be20>: calling -display has no effect.
> 2010-12-21 13:59:22.233 CoreAnimationOpenGL[7496:207] <GLLayer: 0x4e0be20>: calling -display has no effect.
> ...
> ```

So it seems that, possibly for performance reasons, for OpenGL layers, `-drawInContext:` is not getting called because these layers do not use the standard `-display` method to draw themselves. Can anybody confirm that? Is there a way around it?

Or can I not use the technique I laid out above? This would mean I would have to implement the animations manually in the OpenGL renderer (which is possible but not as elegant IMO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried making a parent layer above the OpenGL layer and animating that instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: It indeed works that way, thanks a lot! Performance does not seem to be as good as a pure OpenGL solution but I am gonna write a blog post about the specifics soon.

Answer (score 6):

You can override `display` instead of `drawInContext`. During the animation, the animated value is in the presentation layer.

```
- (void) display
{
    GLLayer* myPresentationLayer = (GLLayer*)[self presentationLayer];
    self.renderer.centerPoint = myPresentationLayer.sceneCenterPoint;
    [self.renderer render];
}
```

At the end the presentation layer will have the model layer value, so you’ll need to set the final value on the model layer before starting the animation.

Comment: Great suggestion, Jeff, thanks. I tried it out and this approach works, too. Performance-wise, it seems to be in the same ballpark as Dad's idea.