# "Regular" drawing on top of OpenGL layer

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How do I implement "regular" drawing (as normally would be done in a drawRect method) on top of an OpenGL animation running in the background? My app is the OpenGL app that is the default Xcode game app template. The GLKViewController does not have a drawRect method, and when I add one, it never gets called. I tried to implement drawing code in the drawInRect method (which does exist) but I get run time errors.

So to summarize: I'd like to draw stuff (lines, paths, whatever) NOT using OpenGL, but using regular quartz primitives and display this on top of an existing 3d rendering.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure `drawRect` is being called, you should probably go the other route: Create a standard Cocoa Touch project, alter the `+ (Class)layerClass` method of the main view to return `[CAEAGLLayer class]`, then start drawing with that. Note that the [`CAEAGLLayer` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CAEAGLLayer_Class/CAEGLLayer/CAEGLLayer.html) specifically warns against doing what you want to do:

> Avoid drawing other layers on top of the CAEAGLLayer object. If you must draw other, non OpenGL content, you might find the performance cost acceptable if you place transparent 2D content on top of the GL content and also make sure that the OpenGL content is opaque and not transformed.

Check out the [`GLPaint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328) project for a simple OpenGL ES project showing the `layerClass` override (in `PaintingView.m`). They use `layoutSubviews` and `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` to do the drawing.

Comment: Thanks. I see that the actual drawing occurs in renderLineFromPoint with the [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES] call. But how would I incorporate regular quartz drawing commands in a layer above this GL layer? I assume that I can't use the same "context" as the GL layer?

Comment: In Interface Builder or code, define extra `UIView`s as subviews of your main view. Each `UIView` has an internal `CALayer`, so when it's asked to draw itself it will be using the context of that layer. The GL context at that point is irrelevant.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500708/marrying-core-animation-with-opengl-es) may help.